# Remove custom resource names from cloudformation, programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sdk

My application currently intakes cloudformation jsons/yamls and create stacks out of them. Currently, the struggles we are having are concerning the updating, since it's impossible to update a stack that contains custom-named resources.

My question is the following: is there a clean/smart way to remove custom names from those templates, and either service-aware or service-agnostic?

I've considered some regex/replacement but I wanted to see if there were a smarter way.

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by "it's impossible to update a stack that contains custom-named resources"? Is the problem that you're trying to use the same template for multiple stacks and have clashing names?

Comment: No, I was referencing [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-custom-name/?nc1=h_ls) error.

Comment: Can you show your template and what resource is being replaced?